# EAGER y Paginación : Spring MVC + Hibernate + JPA Repository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, sql

Tengo una entidad A relacionada con @OneToMany con una entidad B, en EAGER. (y mas relaciones mayoritariamente LAZYs, pero por simplificar).

La entidad B tambien se relaciona con A mediante una @ManyToOne tambien en EAGER. (y mas relaciones mayoritariamente LAZYs, pero por simplificar)

Entonces tengo una @Query que hace una serie inner joins para determinar que puntuacion tienen una coleccioón de Entidades A, y que me obtenga un elemento paginado de 10 elementos.

**Este proceso falla, y aborta el proceso.**

Resulta que tengo 1000 registros de A que cumplen esa condicion establecida en el @Query, y el paginado en lugar de obtener los 10 elementos de A, y luego hacer el EAGER con B de esos 10, lo que hace es lo contrario, obtiene los 1000 A, e intenta hacer 1000 EAGER con B, para luego darme 10

El caso es que no se si es que el sistema revienta, se corta la conexion con BBDD o que pasa pero la pila de errores se vuelve ilegible y nunca llega a verse el inicio del error, sino por cada linea de las mil empieza a encadenar errores...He podido comprobar en BBDD, que las consultas que llegan son esas que indico,

¿alguien me puede explicar por qué pasa eso? ¿cómo se evita? por que la única solución es cambiar todos los EAGER para que sean LAZY, y hacer luego las consultas una a una de las relaciones con B, para poder preparar todos los datos que necesito mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

ya la resolví el problema en este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090717/eager-and-pagination-spring-mvc-jpa-repository-hibernate/43125260#43125260

Se debía a un porblema con el método hasCode() de la entidad B, uqe tenia una comparación con al entidad A, tanto en el hascode() como en el equal(). Parece que Spring al obtneer los datos ejecuta estos métodos y hace que se meta itnente traer los 100 registros de la entidad A que existen en BBDD para generar el hasCode... provocando que aborte el proceso por el tiempo de ejecución y la carga de la pila.

Eliminando esas dependencias en el haschode y equal, se evita estas iteraciones, y el proceso funciona correctamente.